# Pug + AngularJs pass variable function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

Im having trouble passing data after upgrading from jade to pug. The following code worked before:

```
(page.pug)
...
#page-wrapper
    .row
        .col-lg-12
            h1.page-header #{title}
        .row(ng-controller="AppCtrl", ng-init="init('#{title}')")
...
```

I understand they removed some support for interpolation in attributes because " the implementation was unnecessarily complex", but how should it be done now?

Edit:
the problem is that in init() the parameter is recieved as "#{title}" as a string, instead of the value

Edit 2:
The data is passed from express to pug like this:

```
(routes.js)
...
res.render('page', {title: req.params.title, content:req.params.content});
connection.release();
...
```

So pug can access the data in title and content variables, but something goes wrong when passing it on to a function (to ng-init in this case)

Comment: this is a angularjs question and not angular right?

Comment: its angular 1 if that's what you mean

Comment: yes, now angular 1 is widely called angularjs and angular 2 onwards called just angular.

Comment: what does mean the expression ` h1.page-header #{title}`? I remember that the interpolation it's using double {{value}}.
Another question is: `title` is a variable set via $scope.title in another controller? please share a example of javascript controller

Comment: Pug used the #{title} syntax to render the value of title. The value is passed on from express and then pug renders it. The problem is when passing it on to the angular controller where it doesnt get evaluated. The controller is simply: 
    $scope.init = function(title) {
            console.log(title); // title == "#{title}"
    }
Added more example code in the post